# Bolzano's Theorem application

Tags: calculus, functions, roots

I am dealing with this exercise:

**Prove that the function $x^3 - 3x + 40 = 0$ has at least one zero in $ \mathbb{R}.$ and find
out an interval containing it.**

Applying Bolzano's Theorem (“If $f (a)f (b) < 0$, then there exists $c$ $\epsilon      (a, b)$ such that $f (c) = 0$") I tried to get $c$ solving the equation but I got 3 complex numbers.

Could they belong to $(-3,-4)$, which is the solution of the exercise?

EDIT: one of the solutions is a real number, which satisfies the theorem, so it is proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^3-3x+40$. Since $f(-4)=-12<0<22=f(3)$, Bolzano's theorem says that there is a root (real, of course) in $(-4,-3)$.

Comment: Okay, so as long as only one of the three possible solutions for the equation satifies the theorem is enough. I thought the three solutions must satisfy it. Thank you!

Comment: @Evoked I don't know how you did that, but the roots are approximately $-3.7117$, $1.85585 - 2.70787i$, and $1.85585 + 2.70787i$.

Answer (score 1):

An easy and simple to understand way to see the equation is this.

$x^3=3x-40$ means also that the equation is the way to find the intersection(s) of the curves $y=x^3$ and $y=3x-40$ in the plane $xy$

Drawing with a bit of precision the two curves in the same diagram can tell in which interval the solution can be found

See the picture below

Hope this helps

$$...$$
[image]

Comment: Very clear and useful, thank you so much!